# Creating new Dictionary based on key values in list

Tags: python

I have dictionary D1  and list l1 .I want to create new dictionary D2 picking key values from List .
Is there any direct way of doing this or I need to apply through for loop on list .

```
def main():
   dict ={'acct_number':'10202','acct_name':'abc','v1_rev':'30000','v2_rev':'4444',
          'v3_rev':'676373'}
   vendors_revenue_list =['v1_rev','v2_rev','v3_rev']
   



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I want output like

> dict2 = {'v1_rev':'30000','v2_rev':'4444','v3_rev':'676373'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```py
d = {'acct_number':'10202','acct_name':'abc','v1_rev':'30000','v2_rev':'4444',
      'v3_rev':'676373'}
vendors_revenue_list = ['v1_rev','v2_rev','v3_rev']
res = {k : d[k] for k in vendors_revenue_list}
```